# Parse.com Adding Cloud code to html buttons

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm testing some functions locally using my database created on parse.com and the functions run exactly as intended. I am trying now to put these functions on cloud code to reduce the amount of request sent to parse as well as run the queries in the cloud code instead of locally. For whatever reason I cant get these functions to work when I convert them to cloud code. Also, how would I make a button in html that can run a function in cloud code?

Before cloud code, my html button looked like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="authenticate()">Log-In</button>
```

How would I create that button with cloud code that looks like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("authenticate()", function(request, response) {
    var myname = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var mypass = document.getElementById("psswd").value;

    Parse.User.logIn(myname, mypass, {
        success: function(user) {
            // Do stuff after successful login.
             if(myname == "test1" || myname == "test2"){
                window.location.href="itSplash.html";
            }
            else{
                window.location.href="ticketRequest.html";
            }           
        }, 
        error: function(user, error) {
            // The login failed. Check error to see why.
            alert("Failed to login: " + error.message);
        }
    });
});
```

for clarification that if statement just directs login to itSplash if username matches test1 or test2, and ticketRequest if its anyone else. We have a seperate page for different users. Also, that function works locally if I create it as a normal function authenticate(). When I converted it to cloud code as seen above it wont work. I create a seperate function name runAuthenticate() with a Parse.Cloud.run call inside that and it wouldnt work there. All I got was an Error saying define cannot be used on that Object. Any Help?

Comment: Have you checked the error log to see what it tells you is undefined, and have you tried to run the cloud function from curl ?

Comment: I have run the code while in debugger mode. From what I can tell it wont even run any functions so everything is still undefined. Before it runs anything it throws an error at the Parse.Cloud.define part stating something along the lines of "define can not be used on this Object". I tested the sample hello world cloud code posed on Parse.com and it works fine, but something about the code above doesnt work. I literally copy and pasted it from the js file i used to run it locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can link the HTML button with a cloud code function by using Parse.Cloud.run.

Take a look at the Parse Cloud code 
[documentations](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code).

This is how you can call the cloud code from javascript.

```
Parse.Cloud.run('hello', {}, {
    success: function(result) {
        // result is 'Hello world!'
    },
    error: function(error) {
        //  Error while running cloud code
    }
});
```

As you have written, you can try calling a javascript method onclick on the HTML button and then call the Parse.Cloud.run method.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't have access to `document` or `window` in cloud code so you need to rethink where you're coming from.

Also, it isn't appropriate to have the user details sent to the cloud code, you should login on the web page using the SDK and then use the SDK to trigger the cloud code and it will send the user and auth details.

So, the whole premise of your `authenticate` function being in cloud code doesn't really work.

That doesn't mean you shouldn't use cloud code, it's just that you shouldn't use it for this purpose. You talk about making queries but you don't actually have any in the code you show - but that kind of thing is more likely to be movable to cloud code...

Comment: The help/advice I was seeking was more along the lines of why the way I set up that cloud code would cause it to not work. Is the document/window access causing the errors to occur? You are right in that there are no queries in the function. I have several other functions I didnt list that use queries. Those are much more complex so I wanted to try and get this simpler function working before trying it on those. Also, I still have no idea how to run cloud code on an HTML button. If I could get this to not display errors and learn how to use Parse.Cloud.run on an html button that would be great

Comment: Also, thanks for the input on document and window. I was hesitant to add this function to cloud code as it wouldnt improve performance by much(im guessing). I just wanted to see if I could get one of my simpler functions successfully working in cloud code, but I cant even get past loading the page before I get errors.

Comment: having `()` in the function name is likely an issue. Then yes `document` and `window` are undefined so you will get errors there. Parse has an error log that you can look at and it will tell you the issues.

Comment: Remember you can add a function in cloud code which just returns a string  and use that for testing... Have the html button run a JS function and have that function use `Parse.Cloud.run` to execute the cloud code and handle the response.

Comment: So I should probably change it to where my Parse.Cloud.define contains all of my actual code, and then make a function that will just do Parse.Cloud.run and then link that function to the button instead? Even without the () it still caused errors but I will try to omit the window and document features and see if that changes anything

Comment: Yes. And you must go into the parse web console and look at the error log (part of the Core section) to see what it says is going wrong

Comment: Ok i looked in the debugger a bit more. When i look at the Parse.Cloud.define object, specifically at the Parse.Cloud part I can see proto data, Methods, etc. When I look under Methods, the only applicable Method for Parse.Cloud is run. I dont see define, afterUpdate, beforeUpdate or anything else.

Comment: also forgot to mention that even with response handlers they arent being sent to the log. It never makes it that far...I set them as response.success("it worked"); and response.error("didnt work"); yet I never see those in the log

Comment: They don't get logged, they get returned to the caller. Runtime errors and `console.log` get logged.